# manipulating pandas dataframe to add new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe

```
  ticker created_at  entry_price  exit_price direction  size
0   APPL 2023-05-29            1           4      LONG    12
1   TSLA 2023-05-29            2           3     SHORT    32
```

but I want to add another column at the end which would be the sum of entry_price and exit_price times size.

I tried but couldn't make it work any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `I tried but couldn't make it work` - Can you add your not working code to question? Because seems need only `sum`

Comment: sure i tried these "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-pandas/"

Comment: it only shows how to add the coulumn with already exixting data

Comment: So need `df['sum'] = df[['entry_price','exit_price']].sum(axis=1)` ?